# Bucle for con if y elif en una linea

Tags: python, gráficas

de esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787632/different-color-for-line-depending-on-corresponding-values-in-pyplot/37790834#37790834 conseguí pintar una gráfica con distintos colores en función de un array binario "anotation". El problema es que ahora quiero utilizar tres colores y no entiendo demasiado bien el bucle for. Lo he intentando con un elif -a pero me da problemas de sintaxis. El código que tengo, a partir de el del link es el siguiente:

```
x = time          # resampledTime
y = feature    # modulusOfZeroNormalized
annotation = diarization==0

# set up colors 
c = ['r' if a else 'g' for a in annotation]

# convert time series to line segments
lines = [((x0,y0), (x1,y1)) for x0, y0, x1, y1 in zip(x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:], y[1:])]
colored_lines = LineCollection(lines, colors=c, linewidths=(2,))

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.add_collection(colored_lines)
ax.autoscale_view()

plt.text(0, 0.9*np.max(feature), feature_name)
plt.show()
```

Mi vector diarization ahora traerá ceros, unos y menos unos únicamente pero con el código de ahora pinta en rojo los 0 y el resto en verde. ¿Alguien sabe como modificar la línea c= ['r' if ......] para que tenga en cuenta tres colores?
PD: con elif no me deja hacer nada por errores de sintaxis.

Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Dado que usas la sintaxis del operador ternario, conocido más como [expresiones condicionales](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) en Python, no puedes usar la cláusula `elif` como harías en un bloque `if-elif-else`. Si quieres seguir usando esta sintaxis para poder utilizar listas por compresión, la forma de implementar `elif` es:

```
<expr_1> if <condición_1> else <expr_2> if <condición_2> ... else <expr_n>
```

Es decir, puedes hacer:

```
c = ['r' if a == 1 else 'g' if a == 0  else 'b' for a in annotation]
```

Lo que "equivale" a:

```
c = []
for a in annotation:
   if a == 1:
       c.append("r")
   elif a == 0:
       c.append("g")
   else:
       c.append("b")
```

En tu caso y basándose en el ejemplo de la pregunta que muestras sería:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# construct some data
n = 30
x = np.arange(n+1)           # resampledTime
y = np.random.randn(n+1)     # modulusOfZeroNormalized
annotation = np.random.choice([1, 0, -1], 15)

# set up colors 
c = ['r' if a == 1 else 'g' if a == 0  else 'b' for a in annotation]

# convert time series to line segments
lines = [((x0, y0), (x1, y1)) for x0, y0, x1, y1 in zip(x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:], y[1:])]
colored_lines = LineCollection(lines, colors=c, linewidths=(2,))

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.add_collection(colored_lines)
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tu mapa de colores contemplara más posibilidades aún siguiendo la misma idea sería más cómodo usar un diccionario:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# construct some data
n = 30
x = np.arange(n+1)           # resampledTime
y = np.random.randn(n+1)     # modulusOfZeroNormalized
annotation = np.random.choice(np.arange(-2, 4), 15)

color_map = {-2: 'r',
             -1: 'g',
              0: 'b',
              1: 'y',
              2: 'b'
              }

default_col = "black"  # Para valores fuera del rango definido en color_map

# set up colors 
c = [color_map.get(v, default_col) for v in annotation]

# convert time series to line segments
lines = [((x0, y0), (x1, y1)) for x0, y0, x1, y1 in zip(x[:-1], y[:-1], x[1:], y[1:])]
colored_lines = LineCollection(lines, colors=c, linewidths=(2,))

# plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.add_collection(colored_lines)
ax.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]